# Read multiple (all) pending datagrams

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, udp, winsock

I use UDP socket on the Windows OS (winsock) to receive big amount of small size datagrams (it is a need for the problem I solve). Now I read datagrams one by one from the system buffer (using recv() - function). But I want to read multiple datagrams at a time in order to increase the performance of the application (maybe all the datagrams from the queue). Is is possible (and if it is, how can I do this)?

Comment: There's nothing in the traditional POSIX sockets API that can do that. Maybe Windows-specific extensions, perhaps. But with modern, multi-gigahertz CPUs, your bottleneck is going to be network bandwidth, not CPU load. Even if the Windows-OS offers such a feature, and you waste time coding for it, you are unlikely to realize any real benefit from all that work.

Comment: Well, I thought about the network speed (and made some experiments), and it seems to be OK, but the CPU load is 100%. In case of TCP usage CPU load is 60% and the network data transfering is faster. But I need to use UDP only.

Comment: If the CPU load is 100%, that strongly suggests a logical bug in your code, unless you're blasting your server with gigabytes' worth of UDP traffic. This suggests a bug when you're constantly polling the socket for traffic, instead of calling recv(), and having it return only when a datagram was received. Receiving moderate amounts of UDP traffic should not, by itself, result in 100%-pegged CPU.

Comment: Following on from @SamVarshavchik there's no Windows extensions that I am aware of that can do that. In theory for that to be possible, the datagrams would have to be combined within the transport layer whilst they are being received by the destination into a single combined datagram. That presents other issues since datagrams, although having boundaries, can be received out of order or even discarded. There are other transport protocols that might be worth researching: SCTP, DCCP and RUDP but I have little experience with them to say whether or not they would provide a solution.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, I use recv() with a little timeout, so the recv() call blocks. But datagrams come very fast and it is a big amount of them (exactly gigabytes of UDP traffic). Maybe the fundamental mistake is using of UDP instad of TCP, but I can't get rid of this constraint: only UDP is allowed.

Comment: @JonathonOgden, thank you.

Comment: The fundamental mistake here is the XY problem that resulted in you using recv() with small timeouts. Refactor your code so you do not have to do that.

Comment: I tried to vary the timeout value, but the result is the same.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I wholeheartedly disagree with you. Every call to `recv()` is a switch to kernel, and this takes subseconds! It may also preempt your thread and trigger a context switch. Yes, reading all datagrams at once would be benefecial for real low-latency apps. Unfortunately, you would have to create your own UDP stack for this and implement kernel bypass.

Comment: @Alexander_KH, I am with you here. But there is no simple solution.

Comment: @SergeyA, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The Winsock-specific [WSARecv()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx) takes a list of buffers so can perform multiple datagram reads. However it returns the total number of bytes so the datagrams need to be self-descriptive (or all the same length)

Comment: Unfortunately wrong. Using `WSARecv()` with a message based protocol  will split a *single* datagram into several buffers as needed, but it will only every process at most a single datagram per invocation. It is not equivalent to `recvmmsg()` in the Linux API.